# provideAPIKey: should be called at most once (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps, swift3

I'm using Google maps and places API and i'm trying to load nearby places in a tableView but everytime i come in this class

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces
import Social
import AVFoundation


private let resueIdentifier = "MyTableViewCell"


extension UIViewController {
    func present(viewController : UIViewController, completion : (() -> ())? = nil ){
        if let presented = self.presentedViewController {
            presented.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: completion)
            })
        } else {
            self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: completion)
        }
    }
}


class CourseClass2: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {





    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!




    struct User {

        var name: String
        var images: UIImage
        var type: String

    }


    var previuosViewTappedButtonsArray = [String]()
    var locationManager:CLLocationManager?
    let minimumSpacing : CGFloat = 15 //CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)
    let cellWidth: CGFloat = 250
    let radius = 5000 // 5km
    var category : QCategoryy?
    var currentLocation : CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    var places: [QPlace] = []
    var isLoading = false
    var response : QNearbyPlacesResponse?
    var rows = 0
    var users = [User]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = category?.name

}


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        determineMyCurrentLocation()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }



    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        rows = 0
        insertRowsMode3()
        tableView.reloadData()
        category?.markView()

}




    @IBAction func refreshTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        rows = 0
        insertRowsMode3()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }




    func canLoadMore() -> Bool {
        if isLoading {
            return false
        }

        if let response = self.response {
            if (!response.canLoadMore()) {
                return false
            }
        }

        return true
    }

    func loadPlaces(_ force:Bool) {

        if !force {
            if !canLoadMore() {
                return
            }
        }

        print("load more")
        isLoading = true
        NearbyPlaces.getNearbyPlaces(by: category?.name ?? "food", coordinates: currentLocation!, radius: radius, token: self.response?.nextPageToken, completion: didReceiveResponse)
    }



    func didReceiveResponse(response:QNearbyPlacesResponse?, error : Error?) -> Void {
        if let error = error {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let actionDismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            let actionRetry = UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.loadPlaces(true)
                }
            })
            alertController.addAction(actionRetry)
            alertController.addAction(actionDismiss)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.present(viewController: alertController)

            }
        }
        if let response = response {
            self.response = response
            if response.status == "OK" {
                if let placesDownloaded = response.places {
                    places.append(contentsOf: placesDownloaded)
                }

                self.tableView?.reloadData()
            } else {
                let alert = UIAlertController.init(title: "Error", message: response.status, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.loadPlaces(true)
                    }
                }))
                 self.present(viewController: alert)
            }
            isLoading = false
        }
        else {
            print("response is nil")
        }
    }















    func insertRowsMode2() {

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        for i in 0..<places.count {
            insertRowMode2(ind: i, usr: places[i])
        }
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    func insertRowMode2(ind:Int,usr:QPlace) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)

        rows = ind + 1
      tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)
       tableView.endUpdates()
    }



    func insertRowsMode3() {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        rows = 0

        insertRowMode3(ind: 0)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }




    func insertRowMode3(ind:Int) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)
        rows = ind + 1
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)

        guard ind < places.count-1 else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.20) {

            self.insertRowMode3(ind: ind+1)
        }
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }





    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }





    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return  places.count    /*  rows   */
    }



    public  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell


        let place = places[indexPath.row]
        cell.update(place: place)

        if indexPath.row == places.count - 1 {
            loadPlaces(false)
        }



        /*  let user = users[indexPath.row]

        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.myImage.image = user.images
        cell.myLabel.text = user.name
        cell.myTypeLabel.text = user.type   */

        return (cell)
    }




     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    })

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLast" , sender: users[indexPath.row])
    }




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {

            places.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

        }

    }









    func didReceiveUserLocation(_ userLocation:CLLocation) {
        currentLocation = userLocation.coordinate

        loadPlaces(true)
    }

















    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToLast" && sender is IndexPath {


            let dvc = segue.destination as! FinalClass
            dvc.index = (sender as! IndexPath).row
            dvc.places = places
            dvc.userLocation = currentLocation





            /*  guard let vc = segue.destination as? FinalClass else { return }

            let guest = segue.destination as! FinalClass

            if let user = sender as? User {
            */

            }
        }




    @IBAction func IndTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }




    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



































    @IBAction func socialShare(_ sender: Any) {


        //Alert
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Share", message: "First share!", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        //First action
        let actionOne = UIAlertAction(title: "Share on Facebook", style: .default) { (action) in

            //Checking if user is connected to Facebook
            if SLComposeViewController.isAvailable(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
            {
                let post = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)!

                post.setInitialText("First")
                post.add(UIImage(named: "uround logo.png"))

                self.present(post, animated: true, completion: nil)

            } else {self.showAlert(service: "Facebook")}

        }

        let actionThree = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

        //Add action to action sheet
        alert.addAction(actionOne)

        alert.addAction(actionThree)

        //Present alert
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }



    func showAlert(service:String)
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "You are not connected to \(service)", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }









}





extension CourseClass2: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func determineMyCurrentLocation() {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        print("user latitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)")
        print("user longitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)")

        didReceiveUserLocation(userLocation)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Error \(error)")
        errorGettingCurrentLocation(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse || status == .authorizedAlways {
            locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
            //locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
        } else if status == .denied || status == .restricted {
            errorGettingCurrentLocation("Location access denied")
        }
    }

    func errorGettingCurrentLocation(_ errorMessage:String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController.init(title: "Error", message: errorMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

i get the message "error - response status" from this function

```
func didReceiveResponse(response:QNearbyPlacesResponse?, error : Error?) -> Void {
        if let error = error {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let actionDismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            let actionRetry = UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.loadPlaces(true)
                }
            })
            alertController.addAction(actionRetry)
            alertController.addAction(actionDismiss)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.present(viewController: alertController)

            }
        }
        if let response = response {
            self.response = response
            if response.status == "OK" {
                if let placesDownloaded = response.places {
                    places.append(contentsOf: placesDownloaded)
                }

                self.tableView?.reloadData()
            } else {
                let alert = UIAlertController.init(title: "Error", message: response.status, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.loadPlaces(true)
                    }
                }))
                 self.present(viewController: alert)
            }
            isLoading = false
        }
        else {
            print("response is nil")
        }
    }
```

so looking in the console i saw this error "((null)) was false: provideAPIKey: should be called at most once" which is perhaps the cause of the problem (even if I'm not sure), i followed the google documentation guide to get the API key for the project, here is my appDelegate where there are my keys (i changed for now the numbers of the key with "My Api key")

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import CoreLocation
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces
import FBSDKCoreKit
import GoogleSignIn
import FBSDKShareKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate  {

    static let googleMapsApiKey = "MY API Key"
    static let googlePlacesAPIKey = "MY API Key"

    var window: UIWindow?
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.



        FirebaseApp.configure()

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey(AppDelegate.googleMapsApiKey)
        GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey(AppDelegate.googlePlacesAPIKey)


        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

        IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
        IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enableAutoToolbar = false


        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

        if GMSServices.provideAPIKey("MY API Key") {
            print("good provided keys correctly")
        }
        else {
            print("key didn't provided")
        }

        return true
    }
```

someone can tell if the problem is a wrong use of the api key or if the keys are wrong or maybe the problem is another ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at what you are doing here:

```
// once
GMSServices.provideAPIKey(AppDelegate.googleMapsApiKey)
GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey(AppDelegate.googlePlacesAPIKey)


FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enableAutoToolbar = false


GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
// twice!
if GMSServices.provideAPIKey("MY API Key") {
```

You are calling `provideAPIKey` twice!

I know you want to check whether the API key is provided correctly, but the correct way to do this is not to call the method twice. Instead, you should store the return value and check the return value:

```
// put the return value in "success"
let success = GMSServices.provideAPIKey(AppDelegate.googleMapsApiKey)
GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey(AppDelegate.googlePlacesAPIKey)


FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enableAutoToolbar = false


GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
// check "success"
if success {
```

Comment: this is work thank you but i still get the message "errore - request denied" when i come in that class to load nearby places, maybe i can try to regenerate the keys?

Comment: @seran You are being very vague here, and you showed too much code. It takes a long time to go through all your code and find out exactly where you meant by "that class" and "load nearby places". Also, I think this has gone out of the scope of this question. I suggest you try to locate where the error exactly occurred and reduce your code accordingly, and then post a new question.